# Simple JSON code doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, json

This code tries to populate a dropdown list in a form with values. I have tested the PHP separately and the query is ok (small wonder !). I have a similar form whith 3 connected dropdown lists and they work flawlessly. Debugging this in Mozilla, I notice that the **success function** of JSON is not executed. I cannot understand why.

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function()
   {
   $.getJSON("/scripts/033A_GetJudet.php", success = function(data)
      {
      var str_options = "";
      for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++)
          {
          str_options += "<option value='" + data[i] + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>";
          }

      $("#selJudet").append(str_options);

//      var selOption = document.getElementById("selJudet");
//      selOption.selectedIndex = localStorage.getItem("selJudIndex") || 0;
//      document.getElementById("selJudet").selectedIndex = selOption.selectedIndex;

      $("#selJudet").change();

      });

   $("#selJudet").change(function()
    {
    var selText = document.getElementById("selText");
//    selText.value = selText.defaultValue;
    selText.value = "Abcgcfkjsdhfsjkdh";

//    $("#selText").change();

    });

});
```

**PHP** (I skipped the database connection code)

```
$query = '(SELECT 1 AS sc, nume_judet FROM sa_Judet ';
$query .= 'WHERE nume_judet <> "N/A" ) UNION ';
$query .= '(SELECT 2 AS sc, "N/A" FROM sa_Judet) '; 
$query .= 'ORDER BY sc, nume_judet';

//print $query;

$result = mysqli_query($db_conn, $query);

$judet = array();

if ($result == FALSE)
   {
   array_push($judet, 'QUERY_ERROR');
   goto _adr1;
   }

$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($rows == 0)
   {
   array_push($judet, 'TBD_');
   goto _adr1;
   }

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      array_push($judet, $row['nume_judet']);
      }

_adr1:
print json_encode($judet);

mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($db_conn);   

?>
```

**Ajax variant of my original Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function()
   {

   $.ajax({
   url: "/scripts/033A_GetJudet.php",
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data) 
     {console.log('SUCCESS: ', data);},
   error: function(data) 
     {console.log('ERROR: ', data);}

   var str_options = "";
   for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++)
       {
       str_options += "<option value='" + data[i] + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>";
       }

   $("#selJudet").append(str_options);

   var selOption = document.getElementById("selJudet");
   selOption.selectedIndex = localStorage.getItem("selJudIndex") || 0;
   document.getElementById("selJudet").selectedIndex = selOption.selectedIndex;

   $("#selJudet").change();

   });

   $("#selJudet").change(function()
      {
      var selText = document.getElementById("selText");
      selText.value = selText.defaultValue;

//      $("#selText").change();

      });

});
```

Comment: "goto"... Ugh. I suggest using a more modern code pattern. Branch you if's, throw early, never use goto's. Not the problem, though. What does the network panel say about the request? Does it give a return status different than 200?

Comment: The JavaScript gets 304, the PHP script gets 200.

Comment: If the success function isn't executed, then add an error function and look at its arguments. `getJSON` doesn't take one as an argument so you'll need to call `.fail(someFunction)` on the promise [as per the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

Comment: It works now, but only up to   $("#selJudet").change(function(). I had a print in the PHP script, near the start, to check it is working - It seems JS didn't like it. By the way, if I set an $message in PHP, how can I retrieve it in JavaScript ?

Comment: that is, exactly what youre doing already... message is just 'hidden' on server in the database. now, design your json in PHP script and put the messages in a place where u know how to find them on the clientside javascript

Comment: I tried to change the selText.value to some string ("Abcg...") but it also doesn't work. Why ? @mschr: Sorry, but what am I doing already ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possibly an error in parsing the data received. HTTP 304 is the same as HTTP 200, only the contents is pulled from cache, not serverside.

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: function(response, textStatus, jsqxhr) {
     var obj; try { obj = eval(response); } catch(e) { console.error(e); }
     // -- do something with obj --
  },
  fail: function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
     console.log( "error", textStatus, error);
  }
});
```

Use this function instead and look closer at the data. If data is returned through `success`, we try to evaluate the json string into an object. Should it fail, an exception is thrown (possibly SyntaxError) and log should show this.

Comment: Where in my code above do I put your code ? Honestly, I'm not sure where.

Comment: Inject it, instead of the $.getJSON call, use $.ajax. This will return response as a string instead of the JSON already being processed into an object. eval will convert it into an object. You Did check the Console.Log right?

Comment: I added to my original post (see above) my code using $.ajax, but something is wrong with what I've written, the Debugger does not even display it in the list of scripts.

Answer (score -2):

Replace this line

```
$.getJSON("/scripts/033A_GetJudet.php", success = function(data)
```

with this one

```
$.getJSON("/scripts/033A_GetJudet.php", function(data)
```

Comment: actually the correct syntax would be `... , function success(data)` but the first mentioned, with equal sign is also valid

Comment: Removing `success =` shouldn't make a difference. The original code just assigns the function to a global variable and then assigns the result (still the function) as the second argument to getJSON.